# dotnet regex to capture using, namespace and its content

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression to capture the using section, the namespace name and the content of the block.

```cs
using ns1;
using ns2;
using alias = ns3.Class1;

namespace ns4
{
    <content>
}
```

Each line ends with windows CRLF (\r\n).

I have something using notepad++ (with multiline option) `(using.*?;)*(?:\r\n)*(namespace.*?)\r\n\{(.*?)\}(?:\r\n)*\z` but it does not work in c# (I tried it [here](https://regexstorm.net/tester))

I have a console program that finds 2 class files in the same namespace, then combine their using, and namespace block content.

Comment: Why not using a proper C# parser ? Will be a pain to take in account the commented lines and stuff

Comment: I am not very familiar with using a parser but I can certainly take a look at it

Comment: Any solution using regular expression will have a hard time dealing with nested curly braces: I presume you'd want all of `namespace ns4 { ... { ... { ... } ... { ... } ... } ... }` and not have the matching stop at the first `}`, right? So indeed, you'll need a parser, not a regex.

Comment: in most of the files I want to process I only have one namespace block; so matching `}<crlf><eof>` should find the closing brace for namespace declaration

Comment: Try it like this `^using .*;(?:\r\nusing .*;)*\s+namespace .*\r\n{(?:\r\n(?![{}]).*)*\r\n}$` See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eusing+.*%3b%28%3f%3a%5cr%5cnusing+.*%3b%29*%5cs%2bnamespace+.*%5cr%5cn%7b%28%3f%3a%5cr%5cn%28%3f!%5b%7b%7d%5d%29.*%29*%5cr%5cn%7d%24&i=using+ns1%3b%0d%0ausing+ns2%3b%0d%0ausing+alias+%3d+ns3.Class1%3b%0d%0a%0d%0anamespace+ns4%0d%0a%7b%0d%0a++++%3ccontent%3e%0d%0a%7d)

Comment: One liner with `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` package : `CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(csharp).GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<UsingDirectiveSyntax>().Select(u => u.Name.ToString())` Support using inside namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly advise against using regular expressions for dealing with source files. Regular expressions will just make things harder. Instead, I would advise using a parser, as properly noted by @Cid.

If I understand you correctly, you need to merge two C# source files. Here's my solution using a proper parser.

Let's imagine I have two files, F1.cs and F2.cs.

F1.cs:

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using alias = System.Int32;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class DummyClass1
    {
        public alias DummyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

F2.cs

```cs
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class DummyClass2
    {
        public Int32 Kek { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's a quick and dirty program I wrote that merges two C# files together using a parser (warning: not production quality code):

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sourceFiles = await Task.WhenAll( // reading input files
                File.ReadAllTextAsync("F1.cs"),
                File.ReadAllTextAsync("F2.cs"));

            var tokensOfInterest = sourceFiles
                // 1. parse source files
                .Select(x => CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(x))
                // 2. get file syntax tree root elements
                .Select(x => x.GetRoot())
                // 3. get all top-level using directives and namespace declarations
                .SelectMany(root => root.ChildNodes().Where(node => node.Kind() == SyntaxKind.UsingDirective
                                                                    || node.Kind() == SyntaxKind.NamespaceDeclaration))
                // 4. sort them so that usings come before namespace declarations 
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Kind())
                // 5. get raw token strings
                .Select(x => x.ToString())
                .ToArray();

            var combined = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tokensOfInterest);
            Console.WriteLine(combined);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how the output looks for my F1.cs and F2.cs files:

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using alias = System.Int32;
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class DummyClass1
    {
        public alias DummyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class DummyClass2
    {
        public Int32 Kek { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Yeah... Two namespace declarations of the same namespace... Not pretty, but this is valid C#, so I didn't bother doing anything about it. This file compiles and works as you would expect.

Still, let me assure you - this approach is going to be much easier than wrestling with regular expressions' corner cases, and it only took me five to ten minutes to come up with this, and it's the first time I'm using a C# parser, so it's definitely not rocket science.

Oh, and you'll have to depend on Roslyn by installing `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` NuGet package. Though it's a small price to pay.

Comment: the spacing got a little bit messed up but I can run a tool to fix that. Thanks